# Rails helper to call remote upon completion of event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs, iphone

I'm collecting latitude and longitude from Mobile Safari with some JavaScript code. After collecting the information from the browser, I want to update the location with an AJAX request. Is there a helper or otherwise simple way to do this with Rails/Prototype or will I have to do an XMLHttpRequest? I only see `link_to_remote`, `periodically_call_remote`, and `form_remote_tag` in the PrototypeHelper API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remote_function` will do what you are looking for. It will also include the Authenticity Token required for Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at prototype's [ajax](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax) call functionality.

```
new Ajax.Request('/some_url', {
  method: 'get',
  parameters: {id: "1", latitude: '123.123', longitude: "123.123"},
  onSuccess: function(transport){
     //Do something?
    }
  });
```

Just replace /some_url with your route and the javascript fields.
I have included id as a parameter in case you are refering to a model so your action may find it and update it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `form_remote_tag` to make a form with some hidden input fields for the data and then submit the form via javascript.

```
document.form_name.onsubmit();
```